# Android help understand code

Tags: android

Hi I am new to programming and I am trying to create simple alarm clock app in android  can some help me to understand this code

```
public static AlarmActivity instance() {
    return inst;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    inst = this;
}
```

More detailed code is [here](http://javapapers.com/android/android-alarm-clock-tutorial/#comment-159582)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you posted is an example of the Singleton pattern. And here goes a quote from wikipedia

> ...the singleton pattern is a design pattern that restricts the
>   instantiation of a class to one object. This is useful when exactly
>   one object is needed to coordinate actions across the system. The
>   concept is sometimes generalized to systems that operate more
>   efficiently when only one object exists, or that restrict the
>   instantiation to a certain number of objects.

Normally this pattern requires you to make the object's constructor private but that's kinda impossible with Android activities.

By doing that

```
inst = this;
```

the activity "stores itself" in a variable that will be later returned by the getInstance() method.  Using this patter will allow other classes (other activities, I guess) use this activity by simply calling AlarmActivity.getInstance()...which can be beneficial in some cases.

Comment: I would rather avoid bringing the Singleton pattern here because this is not a typical Singleton pattern, using your own words: "Normally this pattern requires you to make the object's constructor private" and I would also add that an activity might get destroyed and re-created multiple times, while a singleton is usually created only once and from that point the same instance will get reused (never re-created).

Comment: @alfasin, well, I didn't say it was a good idea to use it here, but the developer might have had its own reasons for that :) With proper lifecycle management it should be fine. Though I really don't understand why  anyone would ever need an instanced Activity...and where they'd be accessing it from.

Comment: I remember seeing a use-case for that behavior once, I can't recall what it was or if it could have been done differently (and in a more elegant fashion...). If I'll find it - I'll post a link here.

Comment: @alfasin oh, thank you, I'd love to see it. I mean, Assasin's code has gotten me really curious.

Comment: @alfasin Assassin added a link to the tutorial he was working with. They have a BroadcastReceiver in a separate class and they're accessing the activity from there to... set text to a TextView. Just wow.

Comment: Yeah I saw it, but that's a bad use-case, cause they could set the text directly by doing something like: `((TextView) findViewById(R.id.alarmText)).setText(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Saving a pointer to `this` in a variable is common in Android programming:
it will be used, later on, by other classes that have no access to `this` (because they have a "different" `this`) while they might still need access to the context (Activity).

Comment: what is use of this code  public static AlarmActivity instance() {
    return inst;
}

Comment: `inst` is the current object, the current ***instance*** of `AlarmActivity`, It is getting assigned in one of the lifecycle methods: `onStart()`

Comment: @InsaneAssassin as Skynet wrote: once you instantiate the Activity (AlarmActivity in your case) you save a pointer to that instance using `inst`. The static method is used to access this instance from anywhere you want (other classes and etc).

Comment: thank you for your help....... this will be annoying but why are using it we could just simple do the oncreate  and check for the toggle button on/off

Comment: Check this method in `AlarmActivity: setAlarmText(String alarmText)`. Check how and where is it getting called and why.

Comment: @InsaneAssassin you can see how it is being used in `onReceive()`

Comment: ^ exactly, and this is the line: `inst.setAlarmText("Alarm! Wake up! Wake up!");`

Comment: i have further question for AlarmService.java... i do not need this AlarmService.java i can call the notification in AlarmActivity after pendingIntent

Comment: @alfasin I'm sorry, "it will be used by inner-classes"? They will always have AlarmActivity.this for that purpose. The idea of instanced classes is to provide that single instance to outer classes.